# Wildfly server auto shut down after deployment

Tags: spring, wildfly

I am using wildfly 14.0.1.Final server to deploy a spring war application. Passing some time after successful deployment, server automatically stopped by giving following log;

```
    2019-03-24 11:27:31,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) WFLYDR0009: Content /opt/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/data/content/b6/e85bb4bda330a5b3febd424d21871177d573f1 is obsolete and will be removed
    2019-03-24 11:27:31,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /opt/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/data/content/b6/e85bb4bda330a5b3febd424d21871177d573f1/content
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = UtilityMasterSatkhira.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_8_0
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,201 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/UtilityMasterSatkhira' from server 'default-server'
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,217 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,217 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Mar 24 11:17:53 BDT 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,229 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Shutting down ExecutorService 'base_scheduler'
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,245 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,245 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 24 11:17:45 BDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,259 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,304 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,310 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,338 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,338 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,344 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to ip:80
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,344 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to ip:8443
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 108) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,366 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.0.13.Final stopping
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment UtilityMasterSatkhira.war (runtime-name: UtilityMasterSatkhira.war) in 355ms
    2019-03-24 11:37:31,494 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final) stopped in 361ms
```

What would be the possible reason for auto shutdown?

[Server Startup log](https://pastebin.com/MNC0qVrB)

Comment: Maybe you need to add more log content. From the time it started. As only useful line I could see in the current line is "Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal"

Comment: @MyTwoCents, server startup log provided.

Comment: Thanks, @Esty for the log. I think Wildfly was started successfully.
After 20 Min there is some timeout and Wildfly server gets stop. 
Now you need to find what is getting timeout.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I know can cause this is the user session.

If you are running Wildfly as application user ( not root ) then if you log off or disconnect all user sessions OS will send this shutdown signal and will bring down Wildfly.

If this is the case, you need to enable lingering for the user so then login off from all user sessions will not stop processes running with that application user.

To enable/disable lingering you can refer [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/846441/loginctl-enable-linger-disable-linger-but-reading-linger-status).

Answer (score 1):

I did not encounter such a problem on my desktop, but mysql container was running very slowly in a way that I could not understand on my ubuntu laptop. Therefore, the keycloak server was constantly getting an error because the operating system sent a kill signal due to long running process. [This solution](https://phpforus.com/how-to-make-mysql-run-fast-with-ext4-on-ubuntu/) save my day.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened in a RHEL 7.9 (but I guess distro doesn't matter) installation where I had previously manually edited the /etc/hosts file for other tests.
My hosts file was like:

```html
192.168.13.145   myservername
127.0.0.1   myservername
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

And wildfly administration console was listening on "localhost".
This somehow causes Wilfly to automatically shutdown few seconds after the startup.
By changing the hosts file back to:

```html
192.168.13.145   myservername
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
```

tells that you get a shutdown signal from the server. See also https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MysteriousShutdowns
It suggests that you use the Java Option `-Xrs` to get fewer signals.